# Can you give me examples of an LDAP connection string for Active Directory?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, connection-string

What would the LDAP connection string for contoso.com be?

What about for test.contoso.com?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need the servername for where you AD is placed - then the syntax will be like this -

For Contoso.com

```
LDAP://[ServerName]/dc=contoso,dc=com
```

For test.contoso.com

```
LDAP://[ServerName]/dc=test,/dc=contoso,dc=com
```

I don't know if it's useful for you but here is an example of connecting in a C# application

```
    DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://[ServerName]/dc=test,/dc=contoso,dc=com");
    de.Username = "username";
    de.Password = "password";
```

Comment: What about the username and password? I need to assign the username and password in the connection string itself in order to access the information, correct? This applcation is just a little test and will run from a Windows XP and connect to the server via LAN.

Comment: im not sure how you add the username and password the string directly. I have provided an example of how you can connect in c#. Not sure it's useful for you though :-)